# Python3 Multiprocessing with MultiThreading. Odd behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, dictionary, multiprocessing

I am at a loss on this one.  I would appreciate any insights/thoughts more than I can express.

The below code represents a simplified version (for easier debugging) to what we are using in production - but the overall flow is the same.  I see the same behavior in this simplified version of code.

**For context/background**

- I am doing multiprocessing with multithreading.
- I split the number of nodes that need processing up equally among 12 cores.
- Because some of the tasks needing to be done by each core are highly I/O bound, I initialize  12 threads per core
- For both threads and cores, I only pass the slice/sub-slice of data they are meant to work on
- In the simplified code, for each node in each thread, I generate a random number and print that to console.  That random number is passed to the vendor_script function, where I write it into the dictionary entry for the respective node.  After this is all done, I combine the thread dictionary slices, and iterate through them to print each node's random number - seeing if the random number matched what I printed earlier.

**Problem Description**

- When threads are involved (e.g., more than 12 nodes in this case), I will see  one thread's node(s) overwrite the data for another thread's node(s).  This is restricted to threads/nodes processed by the same core

**Debugging/Observations**

- Nearly as I can tell, the data is intact and unique per node/thread up until the time the target function passes it back.  When I inspect the data after it is pulled from the queue object get_output target function puts it into, the data is bad
- My first impulse was to implement queue and lock functionality - but even after doing this, the problem persists

Again, any thoughts or insights would be so appreciated.  Thank you and have a wonderful day/weekend!

```
import multiprocessing
import threading
import queue
import re
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict,ChainMap
from random import randrange
import multiprocessing as mp
from lxml import etree
import argparse

def parse_checks(mdir, outputs_dict):

    od_keys1 = list(outputs_dict.keys()).copy()
    for device in od_keys1:
        dtype1 = outputs_dict[device]['commands_outputs']['dtype1']['command_9999999']['output']
        dtype2 = outputs_dict[device]['commands_outputs']['dtype2']['command_9999999']['output']
        print('Parse {0}-dtype1_{1}'.format(device, dtype1))
        print('Parse {0}-dtype2_{1}'.format(device, dtype2))

    return mdir

def vendor_script(device, outputs_dict, rn, core_index, thread_index, lock):

    dtype = 'dtype2'
    return_code = 'success'

    with lock:
        outputs_dict[device]['commands_outputs'][dtype]['command_9999999']['output'] = rn


    store = outputs_dict[device]['commands_outputs'][dtype]['command_9999999']['output']
    print('Device {2} Core{0}-Thread{1} Stored {3}'.format(core_index, thread_index, device, store))

    return return_code, outputs_dict, lock


def get_output(core_index, thread_index, outputs_dict, lock, myqueue):

    device_counter = 0
    vendor = 'vendor'

    login_func_dict = {}
    login_func_dict['vendor'] = vendor_script

    with lock:
        od_keys = list(outputs_dict.keys()).copy()

    for device in od_keys:
        with lock:
            filterbykey = lambda keys: {x: outputs_dict[x] for x in keys}
            rn = randrange(10000000)
            print('Get Outputs For Device {0} Core{1}-Thread{2} RN {3}'.format(device, core_index, thread_index, rn))
            od = filterbykey([device])
            outputs_dict[device]['common']['core_index'] = core_index
            outputs_dict[device]['common']['thread_index'] = thread_index
        index = 0
        for each in range(10):
            if index < 10:
                if vendor in login_func_dict.keys():
                    #print('{0} {1} Core-{2}_Thread-{3}'.format(device, rn, core_index, thread_index))
                    return_code, outputs_dict, lock = login_func_dict[vendor](device, outputs_dict, rn, core_index, thread_index, lock)
                    if return_code == 'success':
                        index += 100

    myqueue.put(outputs_dict)


def backbone(mdir):

    sigroot = etree.parse('/opt/opst/DART/sigfile.xml')

    core_index = mdir['core_index']

    commands_outputs = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(set))))
    commands_outputs['vendor']['dtype1']['command_9999999']['output'] = set()
    commands_outputs['vendor']['dtype1']['command_9999999']['commands'] = {'command1', 'command2'}
    commands_outputs['vendor']['dtype2']['command_9999999']['output'] = set()
    commands_outputs['vendor']['dtype2']['command_9999999']['commands'] = {'command1', 'command2'}


    outputs_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict)))))

    lock = threading.Lock()

    for device in mdir['devices'].copy():
        vendor = 'vendor'
        with lock:
            outputs_dict[device]['common']['core_index'] = mdir['core_index']
            outputs_dict[device]['commands_outputs'] = commands_outputs[vendor].copy()

    filterbykey = lambda keys: {x: outputs_dict[x] for x in keys}
    num_threads = 12
    device_split = np.array_split(list(outputs_dict.keys()), num_threads)

    myqueue = queue.Queue()

    thread_results = []
    threads = []
    for thread_index in range(num_threads):
        split_list = list(device_split[thread_index])
        outputs_dict_split = filterbykey(split_list)
        t = threading.Thread(target=get_output, args=(core_index, thread_index, outputs_dict_split, lock, myqueue))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)
        response = myqueue.get(t)
        thread_results.append(response)

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()


    outputs_dict = ChainMap(*thread_results)

    mdir = parse_checks(mdir, outputs_dict)

    return mdir

def process_mp(dlist, func_key):

    funcs = {}
    funcs['backbone'] = backbone

    pool = mp.Pool(len(dlist))

    if len(dlist) >= 12:
        d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8, d9, d10, d11, d12 = pool.map(funcs[func_key], [i for i in dlist])
        dlist = [d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8, d9, d10, d11, d12]

    elif len(dlist) < 12:
        d1 = pool.map(funcs[func_key], [i for i in dlist])
        dlist = d1

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    return dlist

if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('num_devices', help='number')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    devices = []
    for each in range(int(args.num_devices)):
        devices.append('rtr-{0}'.format(each))

    num_cores = 12
    np_split = np.array_split(list(devices), num_cores)

    mdir = {}
    dlist_cpe = []
    core_index = 0
    for np_list in np_split:
        if len(np_list) > 0:
            dtemp = mdir.copy()
            dtemp['devices'] = set(np_list)
            dtemp['core_index'] = core_index
            dlist_cpe.append(dtemp)
            core_index += 1

    dlist_cpe = process_mp(dlist_cpe, 'backbone')
```

Example Script Outputs

To run "python3 XX.py 13"  13 in this case, so there is a single device whose outputs are overwritten

```
19:19:18 root@SERVER:/opt/opst # python3 mt4.py 13
Get Outputs For node rtr-4 Core3-Thread0 RN 9707558
node rtr-4 Core3-Thread0 Stored 9707558
Node rtr-4 Core3-Thread0 Before RN 9707558
Get Outputs For node rtr-8 Core7-Thread0 RN 871973
node rtr-8 Core7-Thread0 Stored 871973
Node rtr-8 Core7-Thread0 Before RN 871973
Get Outputs For node rtr-0 Core0-Thread0 RN 1003332 <== ** Random Number Passed **
node rtr-0 Core0-Thread0 Stored 1003332 <== ** Correct at end of vendor_script **
Node rtr-0 Core0-Thread0 Before RN 1003332 <== ** Correct just prior to get_output dictionary in the queue **
Get Outputs For node rtr-1 Core0-Thread1 RN 7796965
node rtr-1 Core0-Thread1 Stored 7796965
Node rtr-1 Core0-Thread1 Before RN 7796965
Node rtr-4 Core3 After RN 9707558
Parse rtr-4-dtype1_set()
Parse rtr-4-dtype2_9707558
Get Outputs For node rtr-7 Core6-Thread0 RN 4669557
node rtr-7 Core6-Thread0 Stored 4669557
Node rtr-7 Core6-Thread0 Before RN 4669557
Node rtr-8 Core7 After RN 871973
Parse rtr-8-dtype1_set()
Parse rtr-8-dtype2_871973
Node rtr-7 Core6 After RN 4669557
Parse rtr-7-dtype1_set()
Parse rtr-7-dtype2_4669557
Node rtr-0 Core0 After RN 7796965 <== ** Incorrect after being returned.  Seems to have been overwritten by rtr-1 nodes random number **
Node rtr-1 Core0 After RN 7796965
Parse rtr-1-dtype1_set()
Parse rtr-1-dtype2_7796965
Parse rtr-0-dtype1_set()
Parse rtr-0-dtype2_7796965
Get Outputs For node rtr-3 Core2-Thread0 RN 9650151
node rtr-3 Core2-Thread0 Stored 9650151
Node rtr-3 Core2-Thread0 Before RN 9650151
Node rtr-3 Core2 After RN 9650151
Parse rtr-3-dtype1_set()
Parse rtr-3-dtype2_9650151
Get Outputs For node rtr-6 Core5-Thread0 RN 8290954
node rtr-6 Core5-Thread0 Stored 8290954
Node rtr-6 Core5-Thread0 Before RN 8290954
Node rtr-6 Core5 After RN 8290954
Parse rtr-6-dtype1_set()
Parse rtr-6-dtype2_8290954
Get Outputs For node rtr-2 Core1-Thread0 RN 2102201
node rtr-2 Core1-Thread0 Stored 2102201
Node rtr-2 Core1-Thread0 Before RN 2102201
Get Outputs For node rtr-9 Core8-Thread0 RN 7145781
node rtr-9 Core8-Thread0 Stored 7145781
Node rtr-9 Core8-Thread0 Before RN 7145781
Get Outputs For node rtr-5 Core4-Thread0 RN 4886431
node rtr-5 Core4-Thread0 Stored 4886431
Node rtr-5 Core4-Thread0 Before RN 4886431
Node rtr-2 Core1 After RN 2102201
Parse rtr-2-dtype1_set()
Parse rtr-2-dtype2_2102201
Node rtr-9 Core8 After RN 7145781
Parse rtr-9-dtype1_set()
Parse rtr-9-dtype2_7145781
Node rtr-5 Core4 After RN 4886431
Parse rtr-5-dtype1_set()
Parse rtr-5-dtype2_4886431
Get Outputs For node rtr-11 Core10-Thread0 RN 1179280
node rtr-11 Core10-Thread0 Stored 1179280
Node rtr-11 Core10-Thread0 Before RN 1179280
Get Outputs For node rtr-10 Core9-Thread0 RN 8860235
node rtr-10 Core9-Thread0 Stored 8860235
Node rtr-10 Core9-Thread0 Before RN 8860235
Node rtr-11 Core10 After RN 1179280
Parse rtr-11-dtype1_set()
Parse rtr-11-dtype2_1179280
Node rtr-10 Core9 After RN 8860235
Parse rtr-10-dtype1_set()
Parse rtr-10-dtype2_8860235
Get Outputs For node rtr-12 Core11-Thread0 RN 4956504
node rtr-12 Core11-Thread0 Stored 4956504
Node rtr-12 Core11-Thread0 Before RN 4956504
Node rtr-12 Core11 After RN 4956504
Parse rtr-12-dtype1_set()
Parse rtr-12-dtype2_4956504
19:19:20 root@SERVER:/opt/opst #
```

Comment: As an aside, why would your `if/elif` statement in function `process_mp` not be equivalent to just `dlist = pool.map(funcs[func_key], dlist)`? `[i for i in dlist]` just makes a shallow copy of `dlist`, no? By the way, `len(dlist)` cannot be > 12 or you cannot unpack `dist` it into only 12 variables and if `len(dlist)` is not >= 12 it has to be < 12 so the second `elif` test is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is fixed, though if anyone is able to provide an explanation, would love that.  The problem seems to have been because I was making a copy of the commands_outputs dictionary.  Somehow, doing that was causing all the devices/nodes processed by the same thread to have their updates changed to the same value.

Once I create the dictionary uniquely for each node (rather than making a copy), I no longer see the problem.  I had originally checked the outputs_dict object to make sure the output from the built-in "id()" function was different - and it was - but I guess somehow the commands_outputs dictionary inside of outputs_dict dictionary behaved differently.

*Problem Code*

```
commands_outputs = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(set))))
commands_outputs['vendor']['dtype1']['command_9999999']['output'] = set()
commands_outputs['vendor']['dtype1']['command_9999999']['commands'] = {'command1', 'command2'}
commands_outputs['vendor']['dtype2']['command_9999999']['output'] = set()
commands_outputs['vendor']['dtype2']['command_9999999']['commands'] = {'command1', 'command2'}


outputs_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict)))))

lock = threading.Lock()

for device in mdir['devices'].copy():
    vendor = 'vendor'
    with lock:
        outputs_dict[device]['common']['core_index'] = mdir['core_index']
        outputs_dict[device]['commands_outputs'] = commands_outputs[vendor].copy()
```

*Fixed Code*

```
outputs_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict)))))

lock = threading.Lock()

for device in mdir['devices'].copy():
    vendor = 'vendor'
    with lock:
        outputs_dict[device]['common']['core_index'] = mdir['core_index']
        commands_outputs = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(set))))
        commands_outputs['vendor']['dtype1']['command_9999999']['output'] = set()
        commands_outputs['vendor']['dtype1']['command_9999999']['commands'] = {'command1', 'command2'}
        commands_outputs['vendor']['dtype2']['command_9999999']['output'] = set()
        commands_outputs['vendor']['dtype2']['command_9999999']['commands'] = {'command1', 'command2'}          
        outputs_dict[device]['commands_outputs'] = commands_outputs
```